# Merge two observable of different types

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following functions:

```
  getNetworkByName(prefix: string): Observable<Network[]> {
return this.http.get<Network[]>(this.Url + '/networks/search?name-prefix=' + prefix)
  .catch(handleError); }
```

and

```
getNetwork(id: number): Observable<Network> {
return this.http.get<Network>(this.Url + '/networks/' + id)
  .catch(handleError); }
```

I would like to have another function such as 
`getNetworkByNameAndId(prefix: string | number): observable<network[]>` which  merge the result from the previous  function. I have tried merge operator but did not work due different types.

How this can be solved efficiently without subscribing to the functions. I need to solve this in the frontend.  In some cases my network name can be 1&1, also  a network Id might be internally 1 so  I would like to perform search based on name and id. I did something like this :

```
return this.getNetworkByName(prefix.toString()).pipe(merge(this.getNetwork(parseInt(prefix,10)));
```

I get an error

```
Type 'Observable<Network | Network[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Network[]>'.
```

Regards

Comment: You can have different types with `merge`, post your attempt and let's see what we can do about it (see [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ozzkp8))

Comment: not enough information, your 3rd function says it can be either, and that means one of the two given functions will be usable... How do you expect to call both 1 arg?

Comment: In some cases my network name can be 1&1, also  a network Id might be internally 1 so  I would like to perform search based on name and id. I did somthing like this : return this.getNetworkByName(prefix.toString()).pipe(merge(this.getNetwork(parseInt(prefix,10)));

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```js
getNetworkByNameAndId(name : string, id : number): Observable<Network[]> {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        getNetworkByName(name),
        getNetwork(id)
    ).map(([a, b]) => [...a, b]);
}
```

Comment: `OP` mentions a prefix argument... you shouldn't be doing his job for him given that he hasn't told us enough info on where he is stuck

Comment: The answer provided works fine, I was able to do what I want with forkjoin